# Wifi problem in OSX 10.7.1 after wake from sleep

Tags: macos, wifi, macbook-pro

Basically it takes very long (sometimes up to 5 minutes) to reconnect to wifi after waking my Macbook Air (june '11 model) running OSX 10.7.1
It does show a list of available networks when I click the wifi icon and it does include the network I want to connect to, but it doesn't do anything if I click the network name.

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Seems to be new with 10.7.1, because I don't recall this occurring before updating from 10.7.0.

Comment: Loads of people seeing this: http://twitter.com/#!/dhh/status/111136661206876160

Answer (score 1):

Seems these issues will be fixed in 10.7.2—maybe you'll just have to wait a few more days until things will get back to normal.